# GCC inline assembly error: asm-specifier for variable '%al' conflicts with asm clobber list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

Sorry for so many questions, but I've encountered yet another cryptic error trying to compile the following inline assembly (with **-fasm-blocks**) which works in **MSVC**, but apparently not in **GCC** and wasn't able to deal with it:

```
unsigned char testData = 128;

__asm
{
    // ...
    mov al, testData
    mov ah, al // error: asm-specifier for variable '%al' conflicts with asm clobber list
    shl eax, 16
    // ...
};
```

What is this **clobber list** and what is wrong with it?

I also tried to change optimization level, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be some bug in gcc (maybe __asm blocks have implicit clobbering). Anyway there are many workarounds:

```
__asm
{
    // ...
    mov ah, testData
    mov al, ah
    shl eax, 16
    // ...
};
```

or

```
__asm
{
    // ...
    mov al, testData
    mov ah, testData
    shl eax, 16
    // ...
};
```

or

```
__asm
{
    // ...
    movzx eax, testData
    imul eax, 0x0101
    shl eax, 16
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the clobber-list is explained here: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html, but not in the context of your __asm syntax, with which I'm not familiar. Trying to compile your snippet I get

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ make test
cc     test.c   -o test
test.c:4: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
```

Comment: is that an Apple-only option? gcc on Linux doesn't recognize it

Comment: Yes, it's apple-only and somewhat buggy. Additionally it incurs a heavy performance penalty for the implicit clobbered register saving.